# Get Variable from Heroku for config.JSON

Tags: json, variables, heroku, environment-variables, config

Being not a developper (at all), but trying to understand a little bit, I would like to change something in my code to protect it a little bit more.

I have an API running on Node.JS, using JSON, on Heroku. 
In my Config folder, my config.json is explicitly showing my database credentials (all of them), and this is not good and not secure for me.

It looks like this :

```
{
  "Production": {
    "username": "abcdefgh",
    "password": "123456789",
    "database": "DATABASENAME",
    "host": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "dialect": "mysql"
```

I would like to know how to get the environment Config Variable I added on Heroku, in this code, to not show the credentials.

I looked on the internet and read about the process.env., but seems that JSON doesn't support that (?).

Thank you in advance for you help !